# How to create PDF reports using PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, pdf-generation

Is there PL/SQL package or engine available which would enable the creation of PDF reports from stored procedures?

Comment: Their is several. Are you looking for a commercial packege, do you have a budget, or are you looking for an open source pdf generator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your looking for a freeware or open source package, their is this. I've not used it, but it has good reviews.  [lPL_FPDF](http://reseau.erasme.org/PL-FPDF,1337)  If you have a budget, then this, which enterprise class product, meaning excellent documentation, is available. [plpdf](http://plpdf.com/).

The commercial package is written in native Pl/SQL so will be very easy to use. The open source package I don't know.

If your running in an Oracle environment, with any of the reports servers,  then all of then support PDF being emitted both to the printer and stored in the db as blobs. 
Its a fairly tedious task to configure it, from what I remember.

Hope that gets you started.
B

Answer (score 1):

PL_FPDF has many problems, such as 32k page limitations and many bugs.  I've modified the code and renamed it to wpdf.  You can get wpdf here: http://databaseknowledge.com/services.htm

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into Oracle Application Express to create PDF reports, but depending on how the output is coming out from your stored procedure, it may not be an easy tool to use.

You can find directions here:
http://www.oracle.com/technology/obe/apex/apex31nf/apex31rpt.htm#t1

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle Application Express - printing features](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/application_express/html/configure_printing.html) not to be forgotten. You can use interactive reporting from browser and decide what you need to print. You can apply XSLT also and decide the printing format.

Comment: Why downvote? I would like to know, so that I get a chance to explain and correct.